# Client is gone, closing socket in flask-socketio

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio, flask-sockets

I'm currently trying to understand how sockets work. I'm using Flask-socketio and a python socketio client and running through a basic example. Here is what I have done so far

**Usage Module**

```
-i https://pypi.org/simple
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.0
confluent-kafka==1.1.0
dependency-injector==3.14.7
docker==4.0.2
flask-socketio==4.2.1
flask==1.1.1
idna==2.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
jinja2==2.10.1
markupsafe==1.1.1
python-engineio==3.10.0
python-socketio==4.4.0
requests==2.22.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.25.3
websocket-client==0.56.0
werkzeug==0.15.5
```

**server.py**

```
import json
import logging
import os
import sys
import threading
from threading import Lock
from containers import Configs, Consumers, Managers
from errors import ObjectNotFound
from flask import  Response
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room, \
close_room, rooms, disconnect
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, \
copy_current_request_context
import sys, traceback
# Configure logger
logging.basicConfig(
level=logging.ERROR,
format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
)

broker = 'localhost:9092'
# Check environment variable
if 'KAFKA_BROKER' in os.environ:
   broker = os.environ['KAFKA_BROKER']
elif len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1]:
   node_id = sys.argv[1]

   # Override configuration
   Configs.config.override({
   'broker': broker,
   'groupId': 'grpactconsumer'
   })
   async_mode = None
   api = Flask(__name__)
   api.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
   socketio = SocketIO(
            api,
            async_handlers=False,
            ping_timeout=60,
            async_mode=async_mode,
            cors_allowed_origins="*",
            always_connect=True,
            engineio_logger=True
            )
   thread = None
   thread_lock = Lock()
   logging.getLogger('engineio').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

   stat_consumer = Consumers.consumer()
   def worker(topic):
       def on_receive(value):
            socketio.sleep(0)
            socketio.emit('object_stat', value, namespace='/event')

       stat_consumer.consume([topic], on_receive)


   worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=['Stats'])
   worker_thread.start()

def on_event_received():
    socketio.emit('object_event', {}, namespace='/event')


# Start listening events
object_manager = Managers.object_manager()
object_manager.listen_events(['Events'], on_event_received)





@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/event')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected', request.sid)



@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    logging.error('received json: ' + str(json))
    print('received json: ' + str(json))

# CORS Policy handlers
@api.after_request
def after_request(response):
    header = response.headers
    header['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    return response





# Object not found error handler for api
@api.errorhandler(ObjectNotFound)
def not_found_exception(error):
    return json.dumps({}), 404, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}


# Unhandled error handler for api
@api.errorhandler(Exception)
def unhandled_exception(error):
    return json.dumps({}), 500, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}


# Node Endpoints
@api.route('/node/list', methods=['GET'])
def list_nodes():
    nodes = object_manager.node.list()
    objects = {'nodes': nodes}
    return json.dumps(objects, indent=4), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}


# Service Endpoints
@api.route('/service', methods=['POST'])
def create_service():
    service_id = object_manager.service.create(
        request.json['name'],
        request.json['image'],
        request.json['command'],
        request.json['node_labels'],
        request.json['customer_id'],
        request.json['application_id'],
        request.json['limit']
      )

    return json.dumps({'success': True, 'id': service_id}), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}


@api.route('/service/<service_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_service(service_id):
    service = object_manager.service.get(service_id)
    return Response(json.dumps(service, indent=4), mimetype='application/json')


@api.route('/service/<service_id>/migrate', methods=['PUT'])
def migrate_service(service_id):
    object_manager.service.migrate(
        service_id,
        request.json['node_labels']
     )
    return json.dumps({'success': True}), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}


@api.route('/service/<service_id>/scale', methods=['PUT'])
def scale_service(service_id):
    object_manager.service.scale(
        service_id,
        request.json['replica_count']
    )
    return json.dumps({'success': True}), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}


@api.route('/service/<service_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def remove_service(service_id):
    object_manager.service.remove(service_id)
    return json.dumps({'success': True}), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}


@api.route('/service/list', methods=['GET'])
def list_services():
    services = object_manager.service.list()
    objects = {'services': services}
    return json.dumps(objects, indent=4), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}


# Container Endpoints
@api.route('/container/list', methods=['GET'])
def list_containers():
    containers = object_manager.container.list()
    objects = {'containers': containers}
    return json.dumps(objects, indent=4), 200, {'ContentType': 'application/json'}



# Start flask server
socketio.run(api, debug=True, use_reloader=False, host='0.0.0.0')
```

**client.js**

/**
 * This file is used for socket connection. Any data received by this class is only shared with data.js.
 */

```
let namespace = 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/event';
let socket = io.connect(namespace, {'forceNew': true });

socket.on('object_event', function (msg, cb) {
    $.get('http://0.0.0.0:5000/node/list', function (response) {
        node_data_source = JSON.parse(response)['nodes'];

    for (let data_table_id of Object.keys(data_table_listeners)) {
        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#' + data_table_id)) {
            data_table_listeners[data_table_id]();
        }
    }
});

if (cb)
    cb();
});


socket.on('object_stat', function (msg, cb) {
    let data = JSON.parse(msg);
    if (stat_data_source) {
        let node_stats = stat_data_source[data['node']];
        node_stats = ( typeof node_stats != 'undefined' && node_stats instanceof Array ) ? 
 node_stats : [];
        node_stats[data['container']] = data;
        stat_data_source[data['node']] = node_stats;
   }
   console.log("Object_stats Socket.js");
   console.log(data);
   for (let stat_listener of Object.keys(stat_data_listeners)) {
      if (stat_data_listeners[stat_listener]) {
           stat_data_listeners[stat_listener]();
       }
   }


   if (cb)
       cb();
  });
```

**Errors**

```
linkp-master.0.dey9j12wugl1@vm    | INFO:engineio.server:3f2175ed5d72425da816e24ffeddb275: Sending packet MESSAGE data 2/event,["object_stat","{\"ram_limit\": 61254823575.552, \"customer_id\": \"-\", \"time\": 1575638732170, \"io_limit\": 0.0, \"container\": \"b703eadb700f\", \"node\": \"953mxmlwyvltfrx88ujlpkx3k\", \"io_usage\": 0.0, \"application_id\": \"-\", \"cpu_percent\": \"1.38\", \"ram_usage\": 407266918.4, \"network_limit\": 6144000.0, \"network_usage\": 3768000.0, \"pids\": \"25\"}"]
linkp-master.0.dey9j12wugl1@vm    | f603fce7e2464586ab77636d127d92dc: Client is gone, closing socket
linkp-master.0.dey9j12wugl1@vm    | INFO:engineio.server:f603fce7e2464586ab77636d127d92dc: Client is gone, closing socket
linkp-master.0.dey9j12wugl1@vm    | f603fce7e2464586ab77636d127d92dc: Client is gone, closing socket
linkp-master.0.dey9j12wugl1@vm    | INFO:engineio.server:f603fce7e2464586ab77636d127d92dc: Client is gone, closing socket
linkp-master.0.dey9j12wugl1@vm    | emitting event "object_stat" to all [/event]
linkp-master.0.dey9j12wugl1@vm    | INFO:socketio.server:emitting event "object_stat" to all [/event]
```

Comment: those arent errors, thats the logger telling you that the client connection was terminated and its closing the corresponding socket.

Comment: The "Client is gone" message in the server means that the client is not sending the regular ping messages it is supposed to be sending. Sometimes this error also occurs if the server blocks for a long time and is unable to process those ping messages. If you look at the log before these messages appear you can trace the life of a client using the `sid` and see when ping packets stop.

Comment: How can I do "you can trace the life of a client using the sid and see when ping packets stop". Can you explain please ?